this.router.navigate in child not triggering this.router.event in parent
My parent component code:
 private routerEventSubscribe(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
        filter((event): event is NavigationEnd  => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      )
      .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        this.handleNavigationEvent(event);
        console.log('nav event')
      });
  }

My child component code:
  // re-route to the view component
    this.router.navigate(['view/engagement-details'], {
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute.parent,
        skipLocationChange: false
      });

I don't understand why, but routerlink in the template the parent does trigger a navigation event, but router.navigate in the class of a child component - changes the URL, even navigates and loads that component, but does not trigger this.router.events subscribed to by the parent.
Any ideas where I may be going wrong? Is one router not communicating to the other?
I basically want the parent to know when the child has navigated from one child component to another - as there is some outer html I want to change in the parent, depending on what child is loaded. The router.navigate code is in the child.
